# Uniform topology on locally compact space?

Tags: general-topology

When reading a paper, I came across the usage of the uniform convergence of functions $f: X \to X$, where $X$ is a locally compact space. I was wondering if the convergence with respect to this topology is the same as uniform convergence with respect to the uniformity generated by the one-point compactification of $X$.

In other words, is the **usual** uniformity on $X$ defined by considering the uniformity generated by its compactification?

Is this also true for compact convergence of functions on $X$?

I cannot seem to find any references on this. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: Say $X$ is locally compact. Are you certain you read about a uniform topology _on $X$_, as opposed to a uniform topology on some space of continuous functions on $X$? (Amd what is the uniformity generated by the one-point compactification?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You're right - my apologies for the poor wording, I have fixed this. The paper refers to uniform convergence of functions from $X$ to $X$, and I am confused on what this means as no uniformity has been specified on $X$.

Comment: I don't really know, but my guess would be yes, they're talking about the uniformity on the one-point compactification.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ah, thanks! I was hoping there would be a more concrete reference on this, as I am not too familiar with these concepts.

Comment: you might provide a reference to the paper you are reading